# Shopify Polaris: Select component doesn't update selected option when options are dynamic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, polaris

The Select component of Polaris works well when the options are defined on load, as you can see in the [documentation](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/selection-and-input/select).

However if the options are created dynamically, eg. fetched from an external source, the selected option's label is not updated after we select an option, the selected option's value is recognized correctly. Please check the live sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-fast-7t63hr?file=/App.tsx). Do you know how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `handleSelectChange` receives the new value as a `string` while in your fetched `options` array the `value` property is a number.

`<Select />` component cannot find the selected value because the types don't match.

Just convert your IDs to strings:

```
json.forEach((item: any) => {
    _options.push({
        label: item.title,
        value: item.id.toString()
    });
});
```